# How to get multiple value from mysql populated dropdown and create table using those values

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have searched a lot on the internet for a possible solution to my issue, but there is nothing that can help me. I am not an expert on PHP/MySQL.

**My Issue:**

I have two dropdown select box. On the basis of first dropdown option, second dropdown options will be populated. This is working.

Now I need to get all the values of the second dropdown by selecting one option (like *"Select All"*), or by clicking on a button and post (*which I have used as I don't know how to use the Select All option*).

Upon POST, it should create separate tables for each value. And the table name would be something like "table_valuename".

And also what will be the query to select data from a different table using those values and store them to their respective databases. Databases which are getting created on the above step.

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
  $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','redhat','echodeve_mfb_temp');//set your database handler
  $query = "SELECT bp_id,bp_name FROM mfb_billing";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $categories[] = array("bp_id" => $row['bp_id'], "val" => $row['bp_name']);
  }

  $query = "SELECT bp_id, hospital_name FROM mfb_hospital";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $subcats[$row['bp_id']][] = array("bp_id" => $row['bp_id'], "val" => $row['hospital_name']);
  }

  $jsonCats = json_encode($categories);
  $jsonSubCats = json_encode($subcats);


?>
<html>

  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      <?php
        echo "var categories = $jsonCats; \n";
        echo "var subcats = $jsonSubCats; \n";
      ?>
      function loadCategories(){
        var select = document.getElementById("categoriesSelect");
        select.onchange = updateSubCats;
        for(var i = 1; i < categories.length; i++){
          select.options[i] = new Option(categories[i].val,categories[i].bp_id);          
        }
      }
      function updateSubCats(){
        var catSelect = this;
        var catid = this.value;
        var subcatSelect = document.getElementById("subcatsSelect");
  //      subcatSelect.options.length = 0; //delete all options if any present
        for(var i = 1; i < subcats[catid].length; i++){
          subcatSelect.options[i] = new Option(subcats[catid][i].val,subcats[catid][i].hospit);
        }
      }
function selectAll() 
    { 
        selectBox = document.getElementById("subcatsSelect");

        for (var i = 0; i < selectBox.options.length; i++) 
        { 
             selectBox.options[i].selected = true; 
        } 
    }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body onload='loadCategories()'>
   <form id="reportvalue" action="file2.php" method="post">
<select id='categoriesSelect'>
        <option value="1">Select Billing Provider</option>
    </select>

    <select name="hospitalname" id="subcatsSelect" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="all">Select Hospital</option>
    </select>
<?php
//$a = $_REQUEST['hospitalname'];
//echo $a;
//foreach ($_GET['hospitalname'] as $selectedOption)
//    echo $selectedOption."\n";
?>
   <input type="submit" value="generate" onclick="selectAll();">
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't think you want to create a new table each time.  Just make 1 new table with whatever structure you want, then add another column that serves as the differentiator.   So if your proposed table would have columns `user, hospital` then add another so you have `user, hospital, option` or something like that.  Then you can query the table and add a clause... `WHERE option='selectedOption'` and you'll get the right results... and can add another clause for the user, or the hospital name.  Seems better than another table to me. (use their selection, insert value in existing table)

Comment: Well yes I can use this way also...much easier....but thats the next step..first step is how to get values of each dropdown options and query using them. @RightClick

Comment: put `var_dump($_POST);` at the top of the file that this form posts to.  It will show you all of the values that have been posted to the page.  Then you'll know how to handle them.